# How to duplicate div and increment label from input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Goal: I am trying to duplicate a `<div>` X numbers of times based on a number input,  and increment a label starting at the number 1

For example: User enters the number 5 into an input field. On change, this then replicates a `<div>` 5 times. Within this div, there is a single label, and this label will increment (within div #1 will be Label #1, within div #2 will be Label #2, etc.)

The following code replicates the div the number of times I need it to, but I'm not able to increment the label.

Within the code, `<label> Crack #GOES HERE</label>`

"#GOES HERE" should be the increment number (#1, #2, etc.)

```
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nbchambre" name="nbchambre" onchange="myFunction()">

    <div id="content">                                          
    </div>

    <script>
    function myFunction(){
    var n = Number(document.getElementById("nbchambre").value);
    var content = document.getElementById('content');
    content.innerHTML="";
    for(var count = 1; count < n+1; count++){
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = '<div class="form-group"><label>Crack #GOES HERE</label><input type="number" name="email_field" id="email_field" placeholder="Crack Length in Inches" value="" class="form-control" /></div>';
    content.appendChild(div);
    }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: I add this in a comment as this doesn't directly answer the question. 
But you can add counters in html just by using css: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters
By doing so you won't need the javascript code you're having issues with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `GOES HERE` in your inserted HTML with `' + count + '`:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var n = Number(document.getElementById("nbchambre").value);
  var content = document.getElementById('content');
  content.innerHTML = "";
  for (var count = 1; count < n + 1; count++) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = '<div class="form-group"><label>Crack #' + count + '</label><input type="number" name="email_field" id="email_field" placeholder="Crack Length in Inches" value="" class="form-control" /></div>';
    content.appendChild(div);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="nbchambre" name="nbchambre" onchange="myFunction()">

<div id="content">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you use this example: wich uses let, const, template strings, and arrow function, like so:

```js
const myFunction = () => {
    const n = Number(document.getElementById("nbchambre").value);
    let content = document.getElementById('content');
    content.innerHTML = "";
    for(let count = 1; count < n + 1; count++){
      const div = document.createElement('div');
      div.innerHTML = `<div class="form-group"><label>Label #${count}</label> <input type="number" name="email_field" id="email_field" placeholder="Crack Length in Inches" value="" class="form-control" /></div>`;
      content.appendChild(div);
      }
    }
```

```html
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="nbchambre" onchange="myFunction()">

<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Template Literals in between Label Tags. As use already applied loops using count variable

```js
    function myFunction(){
    var n = Number(document.getElementById("nbchambre").value);
    var content = document.getElementById('content');
    content.innerHTML="";
    for(var count = 1; count < n+1; count++){
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML =  `<div class="form-group"><label> CRACK # ${count} </label><input type="number" name="email_field" id="email_field" placeholder="Crack Length in Inches" value="" class="form-control" /></div>`;
    content.appendChild(div);
    }
    }
```

```html
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="nbchambre" name="nbchambre" onchange="myFunction()">
<div id="content">                                          
</div>
```